# How can I convert a Date inside an array to string? [angular4]

Tags: angular, typescript

I've got this array that contains dateInterview:Date:

```
  public notes: Array<{ idAgreement: string, note: string, dateInterview: Date }> = [];
```

When i send this Array  to the server the value of all dateInterview should be converted in strings. How can i do that?

I was able to convert the value with an onChange in my input but this is not a thing that I can do for various reasons.

This is what I do in my code:

```
this.defaultAgreement.interviews = this.notes;
```

I assign notes to `defaultAgreement.interviews` 
    Which is inside an Object that contains it:

```
...,
public interviews: Array<any>,
....,
```

And then i send this big object that contains interviews.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: `dateInterview.toString()` ? ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following my comment, fastest is this :

```
const notesWithStringDates = this.notes
  .map(note => ({ ...note, dateInterview: note.dateInterview.toISOString() }))
```

```js
const notes = [
  { date: new Date(), id: 0 }
];

const mapped = notes
  .map(note => ({ ...note, date: note.date.toISOString() }))
  
console.log(mapped);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Array.prototype.map`

```
let newArray = notes.map(({ idAgreement, note, dateInterview }) => ({ idAgreement, note, dateInterview: dateInterview.toString() }));
```

Comment: Wrong `map` signature

Comment: @trichetriche fixed